# Setters from Rails4 InstanceMethods for non-existing fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getter-setter, ruby-on-rails-4.2, instance-methods

I am writing a gem rails4 where i can add dynamic attributes which wont persist in the actual model table, rather it will save in my second table with a reference.

Now i have before_validation to an instance method, where i am trying to set the default value to dynamically added attribute.
I am getting the error as

```
can't write unknown attribute
```

The code is

```
self[attr_name.to_sym]=attr_type[:default_value]
```

Kindly advice on this, how to do setters from the instance method for the non-existing fields.

I have used instance_variable_set for the same in ClassMethods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr_accessor` method for this purpose in your model.

```
class Sample << ActiveRecord::Base  

  attr_accessor :attr_name  

  #setter method
  def attr_name=(val)
    self[:attr_name] = val
  end  

  #getter method
  def attr_name
     self[:attr_name]
  end
end
```

Now, you can call any where instance method like following.

`self[attr_name.to_sym]=attr_type[:default_value]`